# Update magento cart programmatically on place order

Tags: magento, cart

help, ideas already ended... i have config.xml:

```
     <global>
    <models>
        <ordernow>
            <class>My_OrderNow_Model</class>
        </ordernow>
    </models>
    <events>
        <cms_page_render>
            <observers>
                <OrderNowCheckout>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>ordernow/observer</class>
                    <method>OrderNowCheckout</method>
                </OrderNowCheckout>
            </observers>
        </cms_page_render>
        <sales_order_place_before>
            <observers>
                <OrderNowChange>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>ordernow/observer</class>
                    <method>OrderNowChange</method>
                </OrderNowChange>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_before>
    </events>
</global>
```

and observer.php

```
<?php
class My_OrderNow_Model_Observer
{
    public function OrderNowCheckout($observer)
    {

foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){
     Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();
     }
$id = '20'; 
$qty = '1';
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => $qty));
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect('onepagecheckout/')->sendResponse();
  mage::log('OrderNowCheckout');
}
    public function OrderNowChange($observer)
    {
$id = '20'; 
$qty = '35'; /
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => $qty));
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
 mage::log('OrderNowChange');
    }
}
```

When im place order, my observer get in to my function OrderNowChange, but in finally order come with 1 qty items (must be 35 qty). Log show what i need but mage dont do that.
What i'm wrong?

Comment: or maybe someone tell another way to update product qty on onepagecheckout? maybe select box with selecteble Qty...

Comment: i'm totally mad. we add one product to cart for example and when user place the order, it automaticly change for the desired quantity, product just one. i made correct code, right? what wrong, i don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I thought ,it can be event issue.you can used

```
controller_action_layout_render_before_checkout_onepage_saveOrder
```

instead of `sales_order_place_before`

Comment: you need to fire any event before run the code " $this->getOnepage()->saveOrder();" on checkout/controllers/onepagecController.php

Comment: please give me example how do this?

Answer (score 0):

use `sales_order_place_after` observer and

use the following code

```
                    $qty =35;
        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');

        $cart->init();
        $cart->addProduct($my_product, array('qty' => $qty));
        $cart->save();
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Yours code looks good. Just change the observer.

Comment: i'm gone crazy - dont work too.  2014-04-22T08:42:19+00:00 DEBUG (7): OrderNowChange
2014-04-22T08:42:19+00:00 DEBUG (7): Qty: 35   But order come with Qty: 1

Comment: ok...do one thing..why are you declaring qty as string ??..declare it as integer..$qty = 35; not $qty = '35';..this may help.

Comment: I simply shocked! ! ! doesn't work, help please, a code correct, what can be?

Comment: im already apply to product id, i dont know what to do(((( must be working, but no.

Comment: cache already disabled, code from begining apply product id, or i'm wrong? $id = '20';  this is my product id

Comment: btw, if in method OrderNowCheckout set different qty (example 2) order comes with 2, but i need change qty in method OrderNowChange